# Automating DMG build in Xcode 4.0

Tags: xcode, macos, dmg

I've just updated to Xcode 4.0.2 and I have a project which builds a DMG file as part of the final build phase. This worked great in Xcode 3.2.x but is broken in Xcode 4 because of the way it builds a release version when building to archive. Is there a way to make Xcode 4 build a release version into a Release folder just like Xcode 3.2 did so I can automate the DMG build?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the menu Product>Edit scheme. Then ensure to select the Deployment target. Open the Archive section, select the Post-action item, and add a new shell script action.

Then type your commands for creating the DMG. You could for example use the `hdiutil` command:

```
hdiutil create $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/Archive.dmg -srcfolder $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR -ov
```

Comment: Would be good if you included the source/reference for this information.

Comment: How can I add background image  and layout (size etc.) to the dmg?